# search keywords in a folder and split output using the same keys

Tags: linux, grep

I need to search for these keywords on Linux

- render done in
- rendering image at
- CPU @

contained in a folder with several .txt files.

using `grep` I obtained the following output listed in 3 different lines

```
1 x Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7920X CPU @ 2.90GHz (12 cores, 24 logical) with 63929MB
rendering image at 640 x 480, 1 AA sample
render done in 1:17.135
```

What I need now is to split it using the same keywords (`render done in` `rendering image at` `CPU @`) so that the output looks like
`render done in` `1:17.135`
`rendering image at` `640 x 480`
`CPU @` `2.90GHz`

In practice I need the values to be separated by its descriptions, so in can easily point to it and make further calculation (in excel or similar).
if the output will be a .xls or .csv file it would be great if these fields will be contained in different cells.

I'm currently using this command

```
grep -E -r 'render done in|rendering image at|CPU @' /home/ciara/Documents/Logs/ > /home/ciara/Documents/output.txt
```

and I tried to split with `cut` or `awk` but I didn't succeed.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to reorder the items you need to use some sort of language that makes it easy. For example, perl, python, awk. Here it is in awk:

```
/CPU @/ {
   freq=$8
   getline
   res=$4" x "substr($6,1,length($6)-1)
   getline
   t=$4
   print "render done in " t " rendering image at " res " CPU @ " freq
   next
}
```

You can easily adjust the print statement to sprinkle commas there and use the result as a csv.